# SQL: How to get subtract AVGs derived based on value of third column

Tags: mysql, union

**I want to get the difference of two averages based on the value of a third column.**

I used UNION to create a table out of two tables, one with the average rating (avgstars) of each movies (title) whose year is before 1980 and the other for those after 1980.

```
title   avgstars    year
m1       3          pre1980
m2       4.5        pre1980
m3       2.5        pre1980
m4       4          post1980
m5       2.5        post1980
m6       3.333      post1980
```

**How can I subtract post1980 value from the pre1980 value (3.333-3.277)??**

The code I wrote below returns:

```
year       avg(foo.avgstars)
pre1980    3.33333333
post1980   3.27776667


SELECT year, AVG(foo.avgstars)
FROM 
(SELECT title, AVG(stars) AS avgstars, 'pre1980' AS year 
FROM Movie JOIN Rating USING (mID)
WHERE year < 1980
GROUP BY title
UNION
SELECT title, AVG(stars) AS avgstars, 'post1980' AS year
FROM Movie JOIN Rating USING (mID)
WHERE year > 1980
GROUP BY title) AS foo
GROUP BY year DESC;
```

[Note: I started out with a table with many duplicate titles each with various ratings (stars) and years].

Comment: I guess you last line is `ORDER BY year DESC;`?

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional on the AVG, if not match will return NULL and wont be part of the calculation.

```
 SELECT AVG( CASE WHEN year < 1980 THEN foo.avgstars END)
      - AVG( CASE WHEN year >= 1980 THEN foo.avgstars END)
 FROM Movie JOIN Rating USING (mID)
```

- and what about when `year = 1980`?? I put on the second part.